# keep option disabled while condition is true

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a select with several options. Each of the options comes from a db where I also have a timestamp of the last time the option have been used. I'd like to keep that option disabled if it has been used in the last 30 seconds. What I don't know how to handle this situation: I open the page and an option is disabled: for example the option have been used 15 seconds ago. After 15 seconds more the option should be enabled again.
My code so far handle only the first part of this case:

```
var ds = "<?php echo $myPage['lastmsg']; ?>"; 
var dateArray = ds.split(" ");  // split the date and time 
var ds1 = dateArray[0].split("-"); // split each parts in date
var ds2 = dateArray[1].split(":"); // split each parts in time
var newDate = new Date(ds1[0], (+ds1[1] - 1), ds1[2], ds2[0], ds2[1], ds2[2]).getTime(); //parse it
var currentDate = new Date().getTime();
var diff = currentDate - newDate;
if(diff < 30){
    $(this).attr('disabled',true);
}
```

How to say: while page is displayed if diff BECOMES > 30 then .attr('disabled',false)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply run function after given time that will change state.

```
item = $(this);

if(diff < 30){
    item.attr('disabled', true);

    setTimeout(function() {
     item.attr('disabled', false);
    }, (30-diff)*1000);
}
```

Comment: Easy and clean. You just say: "you used the option 10 seconds ago. So wait for 20 seconds and then enable it again!! Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
if(diff < 30){
    $(this).attr('disabled',true);
}
else{
    $(this).removeAttr('disabled');
}
```

Now if it isn't disabled it will always be enabled.

Comment: No, this is obviously not going to work. The if statement is evaluated only on page load and btw the else statement is not necessary since the options are enabled by default. I need it WHILE the page is already loaded

Comment: Makes sense, didn't fully understand the question.